# How to install pygame.mixer

Tags: python, sudo

I am trying to run some code from GitHub, but it is asking for pygame.mixer.  How do I install this on the raspberry pi?  Can someone give me the Sudo Get command?  I am rather new to Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple! The issue is that pygame isn't installed, which is pretty easily remedied by running this simple command `sudo pip install pygame`.

I believe it should then work! If pip isn't installed that is also easily remedied by running `sudo apt-get install pip` and then the above command should resolve this issue!

Log out and back in again, just for good measure, and all should be remedied!

Come back here with a comment if it doesn't work!

**EDIT**: Resolved it in chat, I just never updated my question :P

Pip isn't in the repositories, so we had to go through a whole bunch of stuff trying to get pip installed and a whole bunch of lovely debugging and whatnot. Terribly monotonous and basically entirely useless. Turns out OP was executing the script with the wrong version of Python.

Comment: It may not actually be this. We are, as of UTC 01:36, still un-resolved and are working on it in chat. I'll update my answer when this gets finalized/finit/resolved.

Comment: We fixed it. Pip isn't in the repositories, so we had to go through a whole bunch of stuff trying to get pip installed and a whole bunch of lovely debugging and whatnot. Terribly monotonous and basically entirely useless. Turns out OP was executing the script with the wrong version of Python.